# Page isn't centered

Tags: html, css

I am having a weird issue, there is more space on the left of my content then there is on the right. The page is http://travisjterry.com/NuvigilSurvey/treated.html

I am not sure what I am missing here. I have widths for my header and section with

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

I have tried putting the header and section into another div to try to align it that way but haven't had any luck.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: You don't even show your selector from your CSS. And what is your HTML? Please show us what you are doing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not include the necessary code to reproduce the problem stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this rule from your CSS, it's affecting the `<html>` tag because of modernizr and I don't think you actually need it

```
.audio {
    width: 700px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: You actually helped me solve not only this issue but another one! thank you VERY much!

Comment: @Travis glad to help. If you feel this answer resolved you issue please consider marking it as "accepted" by clicking the green check mark next to it

Comment: Yepp I was trying to mark it earlier but the answer has to be up for a few minutes before it can be accepted. Despite the down votes i got the question i do appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Add a width of 812px to your html and body tags.

The reason it's not centered is because the html and body tags are explicitly sized smaller than the content within them. The inner most content is taking up 812px of width, while the parent elements are set to 700px. So, all of the content containers are centered, and the actual content is pushing out of it, causing it to look off-center.

As easy way to see this is to right click on the content element in Chrome or FF and choose "Select Element", which will bring up a pane with the HTML code. Hover over the HTML for your inner most content element to see a boxed outline of it on the screen, then move your mouse up over the containing elements to see if their boxed outlines are the same size.

You may want to consider putting an explicit width on your container classes, especially any that need margins or padding, and set a width of 100% for elements within them.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the padding for `.wrap` is expanding the defined width due to the box model.

I recommend using a [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) for all elements and adjusting any widths if necessary:

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border;
    box-sizing: border;
}
```

You can read more about the issue here: [Box-sizing: border-box FTW!](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
}
```

And voila, your section.wrap is centered.

I verified this on your actual site with Chrome's developer tools...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have an .audio class with a fixed width. If you change the width to 700px it will cause the rest of the layout to be centered again.

Answer (score -1):

Use some of these codes here:

```
<meta name="viewport" width="device-width" />
```

Then second one would be:

```
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

However, I have viewed your page in Chrome. Its looking great! No issue at all.